# Set binding of IIS to specific URL with parameter

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, internal-dns, redirection

I am developing a .NET web app.
The app is waiting for some users to enter and select a business from a large list of items, so for example:

If you choose "Acme" the app will enter in
www.example.com/Acme

If you enter "Sony" the app will enter in
www.example.com/Sony

Also, once you select a business, you can navigate to other actions related to the items previously selected as FindFinancialReports: 
www.example.com/Acme/FindFinancialReports/ or www.example.com/Sony/FindFinancialReports/

I want to sell the option of buying a custom DNS for your app specific business.
So if you are Sony you could buy www.sonyreports.com and then in some way the IIS will redirect automatically to www.example.com/Sony, and then you could interact with the web like it was a specific one designed for Sony.

Is that possible? Of course in the address of the explorer if you enter 
www.sonyreports.com/FindFinancialReports the app will be clever enough and will go to www.example.com/Sony/FindFinancialReports/. Always it should respect the URL and never show www.example.com.

I don't know if the question is clear enough...I want to know how I could do that, is this an IIS question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is set up a "catch-all" site (Binding * on 0.0.0.0:80) and then let that site handle rewriting the URL from `www.customerreportsite.com/report` to `mysite.com/customer/report`.

For the rewrite part, you'll need the IIS [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

This type of masking is [well-known](http://www.ramonsmits.com/2013/03/19/iis-url-rewrite-hostname-as-subfolder.html) and [well](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site)-[documented](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/11/27/how-to-create-a-url-alias-using-iis-url-rewrite.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with url rewrite and binding on you iis site .

check for iis rewrite modules rules here : http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module